# Emails old MX, A and CNAME records

Tags: email, mx-record, cname-record

I need urgent help please. One of my clients had a domain(example.com) which they forgot who they bought it from 3 years ago. i transferred it to my hosting account as addon domain, then they told me they had emails with same address @example.com 
The emails stopped working, and after doing a bit of research I need to change the MX, A and CNAME records back to what they used to be. How can i find out what this settings used to be?
with my hosting account settings my client said they are able to send emails but not receive.

I've managed to find out an IP address which is 203.45.192.142 but Im not really sure what to do with this though.

If someone could help me and guide me I will really appreciate it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You need to study the headers of an e-mail received by your client. The headers will show the e-mail server they were using to receive e-mails.

You need to put the DNS name of that server into the domain's MX record.

Then, if the DNS name of the e-mail server points to their @example.com domain, the corresponding DNS name to IP address mapping has to be put into the domain's A record.

Comment: Thank you for replying, below is a copy of the fail to deliver email:

Comment: <maree@kestrelcontracting.com.au>: host
   mail.kestrelcontracting.com.au[216.40.42.5] said: 554 5.7.1
   <maree@kestrelcontracting.com.au>: Recipient address rejected: Access
   denied (in reply to RCPT TO command)
Reporting-MTA: dns; relay.mailchannels.net
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: EE34CADE14
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; info@geekick.com.au
Arrival-Date: Fri,  7 Nov 2014 09:30:33 +0000 (UTC)

Comment: Final-Recipient: rfc822; maree@kestrelcontracting.com.au
Original-Recipient: rfc822;maree@kestrelcontracting.com.au
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: dns; mail.kestrelcontracting.com.au
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 5.7.1 <maree@kestrelcontracting.com.au>: Recipient
   address rejected: Access denied

Comment: You should add these to the original question with proper formatting. Anyway, this tells that `mail.kestrelcontracting.com.au` rejects the e-mail for some reason. You need to check that e-mail server settings.

Comment: Is this really an e-mail received correctly by your client when everything was running correctly?